Cannot remove app in the "wheel" group
Following a change of owner of a MacBookAir and fresh setup via TimeMachine backup (nothing custom or unusual), some apps are now locked and in the user group « wheel ».
Unfortunately, I cannot do anything to remove such app of the system. On the GUI side, in app info panels I cannot modify the app permissions as the lock button is grayed out.
On the CLI side, even in with admin privileges no operation is permitted (rm, chgrp, etc.).
I tried to add the user to the wheel group, but this did not help.
The app seems to be owned by the "root" user and in the "wheel" group like most apps but I can remove the other apps.
Any solution to this issue?

Which apps? Looking at my Mac I think they are all apps from Apple's app store.

In general if the owner changes you should do more than you did so that all traces of the original owner and their actions were removed - I think  this has to be done by the original owner https://support.apple.com/en-gb/102773

@mmmmmm This is not a Mac AppStore app and I’m pretty sure I followed this tutorial when erasing the Mac.

Where is this installed from?

you should have not had to erase the Mac - the original owner has to do that to remove their apps (and yes I see non MacStore Apps with group shell sorry for the error)
